# When I Run my .py files, It gave me an invalid syntax error

Tags: python

I use the python 2.7.12. My .py file contains the following:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print "hello"
```

When I try to run the file I get the following error:

```
  File "/private/tmp/fun.py", line 1
    Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I just use the `print "hello"`, so I don't think it's a code problem
Who can tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Do you really have those lines in your file? Get rid of everything except the `print 'hello'`

Comment: yes I just have one line

Comment: So what is your command you use to start the py-file?

Comment: how do you run this script? maybe system think you run script in different language and you get error.

Comment: put in file only `print "hello"` without `Python 2.7.12 ... >>>` because it is not Python code but text displayed by Python Shell only for information.

Comment: 1 .    right click-> edit with IDLE-> press (F5)

Comment: Is there any other way to run the .py file which I save by IDLE?

Comment: you can't run code with `Python 2.7.12 ... >>> ` (and `>>>`) in any way. Python Shell (in IDLE) is only for testing single line. You have Editor in IDLE to create longer script and save it in file and run in Shell in IDLE or with command `python script.py`

Comment: Don't include input, output and code as a screenshot! Ever. The least you can do to help others who are willing to donate their free time is to write the question as clearly as it is now (thanks to @Wayne Werner).

Answer (score 0):

Put in file only

```
print "hello"
```

without

```
Python 2.7.12 ... 
>>>
```

because `Python ... >>>` is not Python code but text displayed by Python Shell only for your information

Comment: Is there any other way to run the .py file which I save by IDLE?  sry i am a novice.

Comment: IDLE has two elements - "Shell" to test single lines of code and "Editor"  to create longer script, save it in file and run in IDLE or with command `python script.py`